# Camera show black screen in ios 8

Tags: ios, camera, ios8, ios8.1

This code for capturing image one by one from camera,but after taking one image next time camera will open but with black screen(like it,s shutter close).all other ios version its working,but not working in ios 8.please tell me how can i solve it?

```
-(void)openCamera
 {
   if(![PickerHandler doesDeviceSupportMediaType:ITEM_TYPE_PHOTO])
   {
    [PickerHandler showNoDeviceSupportWarningForMediaType:ITEM_TYPE_PHOTO withDelegate:self];
   }
   else 
   {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage];
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
   }

 }
```

Comment: Same issue in iPad for me. let me know if any solution found.

Comment: @RaviJSSI am getting the same problem with presenting camera, second time getting black screen. Can you please tell me how you have solved this issue?

Comment: you can set the sleep method for 1 second when camera next time open .

Answer (score 2):

Go to  **Settings > Privacy > Pictures** ... and check if your app have permission.

In the code, use this to verify camera access.

```
- (BOOL)authorizedCameraAccess
{
    AVAuthorizationStatus status = [AVCaptureDevice authorizationStatusForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    return  (status == AVAuthorizationStatusAuthorized);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this code is not work in simulator.

```
UIImagePickerController *videoScreen = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    videoScreen.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    videoScreen.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil];

    videoScreen.allowsEditing = NO;
    videoScreen.delegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:videoScreen animated: YES completion:NO];
```

Comment: its only for video recording but i want to take images

Comment: i want use camera not library

Answer (score 0):

Implement This method

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:NO];
}
```